# Why console.log in this code return undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

```
var el = $('.container');
var anchors = new Array('jobs', 'portfolio', 'docs', 'interier', 'price');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    el.on('click', 'a[href$="#'+anchors[i]+'"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(anchors[i]);
        $.scrollTo('a[name="'+anchors[i]+'"]');
    });
};
```

Comment: Kinda offtopic: initializing arrays like var anchors=['a','b','c'] should be faster

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Wrong scope, i is not defined there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click that element, `i` will have been incremented to the value of `anchors.length`.

Your click handler has a reference to `i`.

An unresolved property lookup in JavaScript returns `undefined`.

It would be much easier to use `this` as a reference to the element. Otherwise, find a way to pass the value of `i` by value, not a direct reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting undefined is because `i` is actually equal to `5`. Take a look at this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    console.log( i );
}
```

Now after that loop has completed you would think that `i` would be undefined at this point in time because it should be local to the `for` loop. Unfortunately, this is not the case. A simple way to test this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    console.log( i );
}

console.log( i ) // Logs out 5;
```

Put simply, the `i++` of the for loop gets executed after the truth test part, the `i < 5` bit. So when `i` is equal to `4`, the loop runs, and afterwards it gets incremented by `i++`, which sets the value of `i` to 5, which in turn fails the truth test.

So now that you know `i` is equal to `5`, when you do the lookup in your `anchors` array, `anchors[5]` is undefined.

The reason this is important is because every time a click event fires, it will execute the cached value for `i` which is 5, and in turn, you will always log undefined

To fix this, we can create an alias to the value of `i` like so

```
var el = $('.container');
var anchors = new Array('jobs', 'portfolio', 'docs', 'interier', 'price');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {

    // By passing the value to this self executing function,
    // it creates a new instance of the variable
    ( function ( index ) {
        el.on('click', 'a[href$="#'+anchors[index]+'"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            console.log(anchors[index]);
            $.scrollTo('a[name="'+anchors[index]+'"]');
        });
    })( i );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` got the value of the last loop. If you want to access the anchor you can use this:

```
 console.log($(this).attr('href').substr(1));
```